# Internationalization of native Mac menu bar

Tags: macos, javafx, internationalization, menubar

I have created a JavaFX application which uses the native menu bar on the Mac via

```
menuBar.setUseSystemMenuBar(true);
```

This results in 4 standard Mac menu items in addition to the ones I have defined. My problem is that these additional items are all in english and not in german as the rest of the application. My Mac is set up for german and the Java default locale is german as well. Can anybody tell me how I can modify these default entries so that they obey the language settings of my machine?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to set the language of the menu bar directly using Java code. But you can bundle your application and then add localization folders for every language you want to support.

For example, if your application bundle is called "test.app", simply create a folder `test.app/Contents/Resources/German.lproj`. Now when you start the application, the standard menu will automatically appear in german language.

Comment: I tried this but it does not seem to have any effect at all. I also tried to copy a de.lproj from some other program but this also did not have any effect. Do you have any further suggestion for me?

Comment: How did you bundle your application? Afaik you need a valid application bundle with a Info.plist file, otherwise it won't work. You can create one using the [AppBundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler).

Comment: I used the standard tools provided by JDK8. The app-folder does contain an Info.plist.

Comment: If someone else would like to see this bug fixed you should vote for [JIRA RT-40094](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40094#comment-448280)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSMenuFX](https://github.com/codecentric/NSMenuFX) to access the auto generate menu bar on OS X and then rename the menu items like this:

```
NSMenuBarAdapter adapter = new NSMenuBarAdapter();

// Get the default menu bar as JavaFX object
MenuBar menuBar = adapter.getMenuBar();

// Change the name of the first menu item
menuBar.getMenus().get(0).setText("Hello World");

// Update the menu bar
adapter.setMenuBar(menuBar);
```

It might not be the most elegant way to do localisation, but for me it works ;)